# Boost:asio time taken for socket read/write

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have the following code to measure the total time taken for a socket write from client to server. (assuming that the call back method invocation is done on successful write of the data to the destination socket (TCP-ACK received)) Does this ensure that - this time is the actual "network time" for the data transfer ?

```
  void on_successful_read_from_client(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                              const size_t& bytes_transferred)
  {
     if (!error)
     {

      m_telnet_server_write_time = posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
      async_write(telnet_server,
              boost::asio::buffer(data_from_device_,bytes_transferred),
              boost::bind(&bridge::on_successful_send_to_server,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));

     }
     else
        close();
  }

  void on_successful_send_to_server(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
     if (!error)
     {
        posix_time::ptime now = posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

        if ((now - m_telnet_server_write_time).total_milliseconds() > 0)
        {
            std::ostringstream log;
            log << "Time Taken for server write: " << (now - m_telnet_server_write_time).total_milliseconds() << " ms";

            write_log(log.str());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think it does. I think it measures the time needed to get the data into the buffers in the network stack of your OS, but not the time taken for the data to be transferred to and read by the program at the other end of the connection. The only way you can do that is to have accurate clocks at both ends and have the send time sent to the recipient as part of the message so that it can do the elapsed time calculation.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this ensure that - this time is the actual "network time" for the data transfer?

No. It measures the time to transfer the data into the socket send buffer. If the socket send buffer was full enough such that not all the data fitted into it immediately, it also measures the time to drain the socket send buffer sufficiently to accomodate all the new data. It does not measure time to send all *this* data to the server in any way.

> assuming that the call back method invocation is done on successful write of the data to the destination socket (TCP-ACK received)

It isn't. It is called when all the data has been transferred into the socket send buffer.

Answer (score 0):

it measures the time to put the data into send buffers in your network stack.
if you want to calculate the "network time", use icmp::socket, just like "ping" command does.

here is the example in boost documents
[boost examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp11_examples)

search "ICMP" in this page